# Filter using lambda function python

Tags: python, filter, lambda

I have an array containing invalid string

```
arr_invalid = ['aks', 'rabbbit', 'dog'].
```

I am parsing through a RDD using lambda function and need to ignore the case if any of this invalid string comes in the input string
like if input string is `akss` or `aks` ignore both.

How do I achieve this without writing filter for each invalid string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare each string unless the words come sorted, you can use `any` to see if any substring is in each string:

```
arr_invalid = ['aks', 'rabbbit', 'dog']

strings = [ "aks", "akss","foo", "saks"]


filt = list(filter(lambda x: not any(s in x.lower() for s in arr_invalid),strings))
```

Output:

```
 ['foo']
```

If you only want to exclude the strings if they start with one of the substrings:

```
t = tuple(arr_invalid)
filt = list(filter(lambda x: not x.lower().startswith(t), strings))
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'saks']
```

If the input is a single string just split:

```
st = "foo akss saks aks"
t = tuple(arr_invalid)
filt = list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith(t),st.lower().split()))
```

You can also just use a list comp:

```
 [s for s in st.lower().split() if not s.startswith(t)]
```

As poke commented you could find exact matches with a set, you will still need it to combine it with either any and in or str.startswith for matching substrings:

```
arr_invalid = {'aks', 'rabbbit', 'dog'}

st = "foo akss saks aks"
t = tuple(arr_invalid)

file = list(filter(lambda s: s not in st or not s.startswith(t),st.lower().split())
```

Comment: @poke, true, it would match full words avoiding  the O(n) search if we got an exact match.